# Pycharm isn't running Python Turtle Graphics

Tags: python, pycharm, turtle-graphics

No idea what could cause this, but Pycharm isn't running Turtle Graphics correctly.
I'm on python 3.10, Pycharm 2021.3.1.
This is what I see when I try to run the demo code from the python docs:

[image]

The scroll bars on the right side and on the bottom of the window also flicker constantly.

For reference this is the demo code I mentioned:

```
from turtle import *
color('red', 'yellow')
begin_fill()
while True:
    forward(200)
    left(170)
    if abs(pos()) < 1:
        break
end_fill()
done()
```

Comment: Interesting... your code runs absolutely perfectly on my system. Are you getting any error messages? What is your system (Mac, Windows, Linux)? Is it only PyCharm that has this error, or does it do this when you run your script from the terminal as well? Are you sure that your demo code reproduces the problem?

Comment: @SylvesterKruin no error messages. I'm currently on Mac, Monterey. Only PyCharm has this issue, ran the script through the terminal without any issues (thanks for the tip btw!)

Comment: No problem! Please try the answer below, and let me know if it works.

Comment: No luck on the answer below, as I've tried several different code snippets with screen object and it really looks like the window itself is bugged. I'm more confident on it being a PyCharm issue rather than a code issue.

Answer (score 0):

You did not add a screen. To add one, I recommend using `screen = Screen()` right after the `import`.

Also, you might want to use `screen.exitonclick()` instead of `done()` at the end of your program.

Comment: You might not need it. I cant comment yet though

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but unfortunately no luck! Really looks like a PyCharm issue rather than a code issue :(

Comment: im sorry it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm using idle and it might be different from pycharm